# Cannot find the resources in nested routes (Angular 4)

Tags: angular, routes

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import { HttpModule }    from '@angular/http';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { SidebarNavbarComponent } from './sidebar-navbar/sidebar-navbar.component';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { StudentInformationComponent } from './student-information/student-information.component';
import { ClassStatusComponent } from './class-status/class-status.component';
import { AasRegistrationComponent } from './aas-registration/aas-registration.component';
import { AssRegistrationPhase1Component } from './ass-registration-phase1/ass-registration-phase1.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    SidebarNavbarComponent,
    StudentInformationComponent,
    ClassStatusComponent,
    AasRegistrationComponent,
    AssRegistrationPhase1Component
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: 'Login',
        component: LoginComponent
      },
      {
    path: '',
    component: SidebarNavbarComponent,
    children:[
      {
        path: '',
        component: StudentInformationComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'StudentInformation',
        component: StudentInformationComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'ClassStatus',
        component: ClassStatusComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'AASRegistration',
        component: AasRegistrationComponent,
        children:[
          {
            path: 'AASRegistration/selectAASCourse',
            component: AssRegistrationPhase1Component
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'test',
    component: AasRegistrationComponent
  }

])
  ],
  providers: [ {provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

You can see that I have the component AssRegistrationPhase1Component which is nested inside the component AasRegistrationComponent. AasRegistrationComponent is also nested inside another component named SidebarNavbarComponent.
When I access the AssRegistrationPhase1Component by entering the address: http://localhost:4200/AASRegistration/selectAASRegistration
Howerver, I got an error because some important Angular resources cannot be found:
GET http://localhost:4200/AASRegistration/inline.bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED
GET http://localhost:4200/AASRegistration/polyfills.bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED

I can understand it because these resources are located at http://localhost:4200/inline.bundle.js, not in http://localhost:4200/AASRegistration/inline.bundle.js.
How can I make Angular recognize these resources when I access directly to children component whose mother is also the children component of another component?

Comment: You probably forgot the base tag in your index.html. https://angular.io/guide/router#base-href

Comment: is selectAASCourse is a parameter?
should be `:selectAASCourse` with colon `:`

Comment: @JBNizet: Thank you, your answer is so helpful to me. Yeah, I have just added base tag into index.html and everything worked well!!! Thank you very much^^

Comment: @Iancovici: Thank you as well, :selectAASCourse is not a parameter, but I also want to thank you because your attempt to help me!